# how to sort string characters alphabetically in pig latin

Tags: string, sorting, apache-pig

If I have a table as below:`name:chararray`

example :

```
acab
bca
das
desac
```

How can I order the column 'name' alphabetically in Pig?

like this :

```
aacb
abc
ads
acdes
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own UDF.Pass the name to UDF.In the UDF convert the string to a chararray and sort it.Return the sorted string.

PIG

```
REGISTER ORDER_UDF.jar;
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name: chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ORDER_UDF.ORDER(name);
DUMP B;
```

UDF

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

   public class ORDER extends EvalFunc<String>
   {
     public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            char tempArray[] = ((String)input).toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(tempArray);       
            return new String(tempArray);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
  }
```